# testNG group exclusion, inclusion rules

Tags: testng

Cedric -

I have some tests with several tags: A, B, C, in different combinations.  I wish to run all tests that are tagged with A, and exclude all tests that are tagged with C.

I use:

testng ant target with:

groups=A
   excludedgroups=C

Yet, the test run executes all tests tagged with A, including the ones tagged with C.

Is there anyway to make this work as I intend?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement your own logic for this, TestNG's implementation is fairly simplistic in that regards (inclusion takes over exclusion and that's it). It's pretty straightforward with BeanShell, [here is an example](http://beust.com/weblog/2005/09/30/a-date-in-heaven-testng-and-beanshell/).

Comment: Thanks Cedric.  It looks like BeanShell is dependent on using a testng.xml config file.  All of our tests are selected dynamically with groups, wrapped in the testng ant command, so we don't use a hard-coded testng .xml config file.  Is there any way to use BeanShell without this config file?

Comment: Not really, but you can use the second next best thing: IMethodSelector (Javadoc:  http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IMethodSelector.html)

Answer (score 0):

Denali, you can use the function

```
XmlTest.setBeanShellExpression("return true;");
```

for example.